# MS Access forms read only

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a application developed in MS access forms pointing to SQL server database. The connection string on the forms side uses a DB user that has full access to SQL server Database.

I want to make the Access form read only, or say, doesnt want any insert/update/delete to perform on the DB side.

Is there any settings that I can use to make the entire Access forms menu just read only? I have tried making the forms setting like Allow Edits/Allow additions set to 'No' but this doesnt work.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "entire Access forms menu"? Each form's properties must be set for these restrictions. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Better and easier to rely on SQL Server security. Set up another user with only read permissions on the data and use that in the connection or, better still, use Windows AD authentication and put users in appropriate AD group which has read-only role.

Comment: @June17 I have tried doing these settings for every forms, but it still lets me modify and save to database which I dont want. I want to restrict the user from adding, modifying into database

Comment: @LordPeter.. Yes I too thought on that and have requested for a readonly SQL server DB user. But will providing this user details in the connection string at Access Forms level will not give any error on the forms level?

Comment: @LordPeter.. Can you please give more details on Windows AD authentication and how does it work? Thanks..

Comment: Here are MS notes about SQL Server authentication modes:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a form with

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "myform", DataMode:=acFormReadOnly, ... other required parameters
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the `Allow Additions`, `Allow Edits` and `Allow Deletions` properties to `False` for the form and any sub-forms.

Comment: I didnt want to change any code on the VBA side, so the settings changes helped.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best and easiest way is to set the Form `RecordsetType` to **Snapshot** instead of the default **Dynaset**.

It prevents any inserts/updates/deletions to bound data, but allows you to enter data in unbound controls, e.g. search fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices.

In the forms property sheet, data tab, set allow edits = No.

Create a view on sql server for the table - linked views are NOT updatable unless you select a PK during the linking process. So the linked view is read only.

Create a pass-though query. And base the form on that pass-though query. All PT queries are read only.

So the above is 3 choices that don't require you to change or setup permissions on the server side.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your first option is good, the 2nd and 3rd has some code changes but works too.. thank you